# PHP's cUrl not working on Aliexpress. Is the request being filtered?

Tags: php, curl

I have an script for extracting products from Aliexpress and analyze it information, but it stopped working a few weeks ago.

I noticed my cUrl GET request is not working like it did before, now it is being redirected to the login page. Chrome can access the url without problems, I also tried an online curl and it is working properly too (http://onlinecurl.com/).

This is the url: es.aliexpress.com/category/204004798/jackets-coats.html

and the script I'm using:
https://gist.github.com/xAlstrat/29a4b01cd5b2c153f9a6

I've also tried using chrome's request headers from the Developer Tools ($header array in my script) but the result is the same, it get redirected.

Could my request be being filtered by aliexpress?  Then, why onlinecurl works properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I runned script, and apparently it working normally. I get next headers and output: http://pastebin.com/dA3RpJmf

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
<?php 
require "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";
$url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2017-New-Summer-Fashion-Mens-T-Shirts-Slim-Fit-Short-Sleeve-T-Shirt-032/32798976881.html';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    ':authority:www.aliexpress.com',
    ':method:GET',
//  ':path:/item/2017-New-Summer-Fashion-Mens-T-Shirts-Slim-Fit-Short-Sleeve-T-Shirt-032/32798976881.html',
    ':scheme:https',
    'accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
//  'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'cache-control:no-cache',
    'cookie:ali_apache_id=10.181.15.98.1496226301876.152542.8; ali_beacon_id=10.181.15.98.1496226301876.152542.8; aep_common_f=aEhfbgrZ7e4e9UmjuOWm1CANyaLLaqTDc80Oan6/v5duIrtz3XfvQQ==; cna=BIi1EWdCs1QCAS43pj2EYRUu; _uab_collina=149806153775875750712574; _mle_tmp0=eNrz4A12DQ729PeL9%2FV3cfUx8KvOTLFScnF1dDR1dDV2dLU0sDSxNLEwsTR0cjN2dHI0MTM0NzNW0kkusTI0sbQwMTczMjExtDDSSUxGE8itsDKojQIApLsX8Q%3D%3D; aep_history=keywords%5E%0Akeywords%09%0A%0Aproduct_selloffer%5E%0Aproduct_selloffer%0932788134848%0932798976881; xman_us_t=x_lid=bg1134819498lzch&sign=y&x_user=bUBd5Jk0irdh4KaPNADUTaZgZPbhimHjaVryhYI9YCI=&ctoken=18y_131g18r61&need_popup=y&l_source=aliexpress; xman_us_f=zero_order=n&x_locale=en_US&x_l=0&last_popup_time=1496226312427&x_user=BG|Nikola|Mihaylov|ifm|754321409&no_popup_today=n; intl_locale=en_US; aep_usuc_f=isfm=y&site=glo&c_tp=USD&x_alimid=754321409&isb=y&region=BG&b_locale=en_US; intl_common_forever=iP9SzYB6uR11n9PDuziWZV+m6wS5lewBhe0mchSYZzPnAbhr0LZabw==; _ga=GA1.2.1468541176.1496226329; _gid=GA1.2.15678206.1498472399; JSESSIONID=C8CB956B69CC08A9B351C25C869BBF29; _umdata=70724C19E34629158F306CE35FF4594FD67FF1CAB2345D48D8DBB0AA935079C88BF9397A2C0FD39DCD43AD3E795C914C85C011A26645999BFC392F47E8EAF27C; ali_apache_track=mt=1|ms=|mid=bg1134819498lzch; ali_apache_tracktmp=W_signed=Y; acs_usuc_t=acs_rt=4426ebd3d8e64e528a12a78ded645f48&x_csrf=o8z03s_owisa; xman_f=A2GX/Y1rs0cttixwSxevdzKgU2yRTOLeKBX7fdKnMDdXVLpqHphq8YkU+FAR6NBhi7hO5A7zc3/N6J/t/H9GWyHI+NwKJhVmLd4RElBNdA8pz3lnGKz0ftxea14UUDnFXkIy11hLAIx4XZqeotvVY5xqQ2mHDWxJdTYyFGUJp2NUu5sA+A+/LFaZo/EhWIfeloGoaQnpsd2ps2jdCJ6JyDiKEeiASt17bEr5yszxaPRfbd7hfZUA4PIxgI7v5xSjj851b0fxepl6UbWi17mb+nk2O1VDuqt3mITEb3d0ZfzzZpWy9G6CuVbj/20I8NLAlFY52SkZtltbyMAImZfaIaEFhz350zco; xman_t=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; __utmt=1; __utma=3375712.1468541176.1496226329.1498476312.1498478200.3; __utmb=3375712.5.10.1498478200; __utmc=3375712; __utmz=3375712.1498476312.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); isg=AgcHaslcEs7cDpY8UNqaqtarlrsRpIzPoZDqYtndZhbiSDMK4NzOPvZIzj7t',
    'pragma:no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests:1',
    'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if($response == false){
    echo "Curl error: " . curl_error($ch) . "(" . curl_errno($ch) . ")";
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
$dom  = str_get_html($response);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($dom);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the script and it works perfectly fine. CURL also works perfectly fine from command line. The problem is most likely that they have blocked your IP / are redirecting it to the login page due to the mass amount of requests you have sent to the site / specific URL.

I would suggest trying to use a proxy server through curl and seeing if it works for you e.g. `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'PROXY_IP_HERE');`

Additionally, Aliexpress has an API located [here](http://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html) that you should be able to use.